# Array_diff not excluding elements from array

Tags: php

I am attempting to use `array_diff` to exclude certain elements from an array. According to the docs: "Returns an array containing all the entries from array1 that are not present in any of the other arrays."

In my code below I have an array which represents the data return from the database when requesting a user. I have another array which contains the elements I don't want to be included in the array. Here is the code ...

```
$user = array(
    'id' => '9',
    'password' => 'CRYPT_BLOWFISH HASH',
    'username' => 'Billy',
    'phone' => '+447777777777');

$columnsToExclude = array('password', 'phone');

var_dump(array_diff($user, $columnsToExclude));
```

I'm not understanding what I'm doing wrong, unless I can't use a sequential array as the second argument.

What am I doing wrong?

**Edit:**

As suggested in comments, I have tried `array_diff_key` and I get the same 
results.

```
array_diff_key($user, $columnsToExclude));
```

Comment: `array_diff` is working on values and not on keys.

Comment: Try `array_diff_key` http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff-key.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`array_diff` returns all your values from `$user` which do not have matching values in `$columnsToExclude`. The values in `$columnsToExclude` are "password" and "phone". None of these **values** exist in `$user`. The result is expected. You want to do this diff on the *keys*, and you also need to make "password" and "phone" **keys** in the array, not values:

```
array_diff_key($users, array_flip($columnsToExclude))
```